# Use constant in f:viewAction through OmniFaces importConstants

Tags: constants, omnifaces

I'm testing OmniFaces importConstant functionality and successfully display a constant on a page like this:

```
#{Config.SOME_CONSTANT} (writes 4 to the page)
```

If I try to do this in a `f:viewAction` however, it doesn't work:

```
<f:viewAction action="#{bean.someMethod(Config.SOME_CONSTANT)}" />
```

It resolves to zero in the method.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A `viewAction` is and called right after metadata parsing (see [this article](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#758)) and before the view is even rendered.

I'm not quite sure what the "EL Scope" referred to in the [documentation](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants) is, but it appears to be render time only, ie only until *after* your `viewAction` is called.